# Why does Perl function "map" give the error "Not enough arguments for map"

Tags: perl, dictionary

Here is the thing I don't understand.

This script works correctly (notice the concatenation in the map functin):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %aa = map { 'a' . '' => 1 } (1..3);

print Dumper \%aa;

__END__
output:

$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 1
        };
```

But without concatenation the map does not work. Here is the script I expect to work, but it does not:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %aa = map { 'a' => 1 } (1..3);

print Dumper \%aa;
__END__
output:

Not enough arguments for map at e.pl line 7, near "} ("
syntax error at e.pl line 7, near "} ("
Global symbol "%aa" requires explicit package name at e.pl line 9.
Execution of e.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Can you please explain such behaviour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perl uses heuristics to decide whether you're using:

```
map { STATEMENTS } LIST;   # or
map EXPR, LIST;
```

Because although "{" is often the start of a block, it might also be the start of a hashref.

These heuristics don't look ahead very far in the token stream (IIRC two tokens).

You can force "{" to be interpreted as a block using:

```
map {; STATEMENTS } LIST;    # the semicolon acts as a disambigator
```

You can force "{" to be interpreted as a hash using:

```
map +{ LIST }, LIST;    # the plus sign acts as a disambigator
```

`grep` suffers similarly. (Technically so does `do`, in that a hashref can be given as an argument, which will then be stringified and treated as if it were a filename. That's just weird though.)

Answer (score 6):

Per the [`Documentation`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) for `map`:

> Because Perl doesn't look ahead for the closing `}` it has to take a guess at which it's dealing with based on what it finds just after the `{`. Usually it gets it right, but if it doesn't it won't realize something is wrong until it gets to the `}`

Giving the examples:

```
%hash = map {  "\L$_" => 1  } @array # perl guesses EXPR. wrong
%hash = map { +"\L$_" => 1  } @array # perl guesses BLOCK. right
```

So adding `+` will give you the same as the first example you've given

```
my %aa = map {  +'a'=> 1 } (1..3);
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your answer, but basing a programming language's grammar on guessing doesn't exactly strike me as good design.

Answer (score 3):

Perl's [manpage entry for map()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) explains this:

```
"{" starts both hash references and blocks, so "map { ..."
could be either the start of map BLOCK LIST or map EXPR, LIST.
Because Perl doesn't look ahead for the closing "}" it has to
take a guess at which it's dealing with based on what it finds
just after the "{". Usually it gets it right, but if it doesn't
it won't realize something is wrong until it gets to the "}"
and encounters the missing (or unexpected) comma. The syntax
error will be reported close to the "}", but you'll need to
change something near the "{" such as using a unary "+" to give
Perl some help:

    %hash = map {  "\L$_" => 1  } @array  # perl guesses EXPR.  wrong
    %hash = map { +"\L$_" => 1  } @array  # perl guesses BLOCK. right
    %hash = map { ("\L$_" => 1) } @array  # this also works
    %hash = map {  lc($_) => 1  } @array  # as does this.
    %hash = map +( lc($_) => 1 ), @array  # this is EXPR and works!

    %hash = map  ( lc($_), 1 ),   @array  # evaluates to (1, @array)

or to force an anon hash constructor use "+{":

   @hashes = map +{ lc($_) => 1 }, @array # EXPR, so needs comma at end

to get a list of anonymous hashes each with only one entry
apiece.
```

Based on this, to get rid of the concatenation kludge, you'd need to adjust your syntax to one of these instead:

```
my %aa = map { +'a' => 1 } (1..3);
my %aa = map { ('a' => 1) } (1..3);
my %aa = map +( 'a' => 1 ), (1..3);
```

Answer (score 2):

The braces are a little ambiguous in the context of map. They can be surrounding a block as you are intending, or they can be an anonymous hash constructor. There is some fuzzy logic in the perl parser which tries to guess which one you mean.

Your second case looks more like an anonymous hash to perl.

See the [perldoc for map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) which explains this and gives some workarounds.