# Syntax error using map function

Tags: perl, dictionary, syntax-error, map-function

I've encountered an odd syntax error in a Perl program using the `map` function. I have a simple workaround (adding seemingly unnecessary parentheses), so this isn't critical, but I don't know why Perl reported a syntax error on the original code, or why adding parentheses fixed it.

I wanted to create a hash that maps a series of short strings, each starting with '-', to the value `1` (basically a set data structure). My first attempt was similar to this:

```
my %hash = map { "-$_"  => 1 } qw(foo bar);
```

which should, I think, be equivalent to:

```
my %hash = ( "-foo" => 1, "-bar" => 1 );
```

Perl reported a syntax error. If I replace `"-$_"` by any single- or double-quoted string literal, I get a syntax error. If I replace `"-$_"` by `("-$_")`, the syntax error goes away, and the code works correctly.

I get similar results with Perl 5.10.1, 5.16.2, and 5.20.0.

Here's a self-contained script that shows the problem (I've dropped the `-` prefix because it doesn't seem to be relevant):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %h0 = map {   $_   => 1 } qw(foo bar);  # ok
my %h1 = map { ("$_") => 1 } qw(foo bar);  # ok
my %h2 = map {  "$_"  => 1 } qw(foo bar);  # line 8, syntax error
my %h3 = map { 'FOO'  => 1 } qw(foo bar);  # line 9, syntax error
my %h4 = map { "FOO"  => 1 } qw(foo bar);  # line 10, syntax error
```

and the output when I try to run it using Perl 5.20.0:

```
syntax error at map-bug line 8, near "} qw(foo bar)"
syntax error at map-bug line 9, near "} qw(foo bar)"
syntax error at map-bug line 10, near "} qw(foo bar)"
Execution of map-bug aborted due to compilation errors.
```

(With Perl 5.10.1 and 5.16.2, it also complains about "Not enough arguments for map" on line 8.)

I've confirmed that each of the three syntax errors still occurs in isolation when the other two lines are commented out, so lines 9 and 10 are not cascade errors from line 8.

Is this a bug in Perl, or am I missing some subtlety of the Perl syntax, or something else?

Comment: Also dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032709

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`perldoc -f map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

> `{` starts both hash references and blocks, so `map { ...` could be either the start of map BLOCK LIST or map EXPR, LIST. Because Perl doesn't look ahead for the closing `}` it has to take a guess at which it's dealing with based on what it finds just after the `{`. Usually it gets it right, but if it doesn't it won't realize something is wrong until it gets to the `}` and encounters the missing (or unexpected) comma. The syntax error will be reported close to the `}`, but you'll need to change something near the `{` such as using a unary `+` or semicolon to give Perl some help:
>
> ```
>     %hash = map {  "\L$_" => 1  } @array # perl guesses EXPR. wrong
>     %hash = map { +"\L$_" => 1  } @array # perl guesses BLOCK. right
>     %hash = map {; "\L$_" => 1  } @array # this also works
>     %hash = map { ("\L$_" => 1) } @array # as does this
>     %hash = map {  lc($_) => 1  } @array # and this.
>     %hash = map +( lc($_) => 1 ), @array # this is EXPR and works!
>
>     %hash = map  ( lc($_), 1 ),   @array # evaluates to (1, @array)
> ```
>
> or to force an anon hash constructor use `+{`:
>
> ```
>     @hashes = map +{ lc($_) => 1 }, @array # EXPR, so needs
>                                            # comma at end
> ```
>
> to get a list of anonymous hashes each with only one entry apiece.